# How do I debug `Package cl is deprecated`?

Tags: debugging, warning, cl

While compiling an Elisp package from github, I get the

> Warning: Package cl is deprecated

**How do I find out what triggers it?**

The specific file that triggers this is tiny and has no CL code.

I think there should be a way to turn the warning into an error and get the stack trace.
Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Go find cl.el and rename it. This way you will get a trace back from the debugger.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the following in an Emacs session with the code in question loaded up:

```
(require 'loadhist)
(file-dependents (feature-file 'cl))
```

Comment: if using 27.1 you can use `(setq byte-complile-warnings '(not cl-functions))` accordingly to `byte-complile-warnings` documentation.

Comment: Hm, I tried that, in both my `~/.emacs` and some system files (below `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/`, this being Debian/Ubuntu) but no luck.  It also prevents `emacs --daemon` from working as the load hangs at the warning :-/

Comment: Use it interactively (like by pasting it into the scratch buffer and `M-x eval-buffer`), not in your init file.

Comment: I get the same warning when starting emacs, but no output from the code above... :-(

Comment: Correction of the comment that shows how to suppress the warning:`(setq byte-compile-warnings '((not cl-functions)))`

Comment: https://github.com/rolandwalker/list-utils/issues/6